# How to trigger slideToggle(); when a visitor visits another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a piece of code which triggers a `slideToggle()` after a 2 second wait on a page.

Now, this is not something I want to show to visitors who have the intention to immediately leave (bounce) from my site.

I determined that the best time to show the div is when a visitor has landed on my page, and navigated to another page.

So right now my code is this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    jQuery(".slide-div").slideToggle();
  }, 2000);



});
</script>
```

Is there a way to listen to a visitor's behavior and trigger a function (`slideToggle()` in this case) when this visitor has navigated to another page?

This way, I can show my div to people who have navigated the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, I ended up using PHP to solve this problem.

Explanation: Each time a person navigates (or refreshes) the page, +1 is added to the `$_SESSION['count']` variable. Then in footer.php I wrote a simple `if else` statement to determine wether my function should appear or not. `wonderplugin` is just a plug-in that checks if a visitor is on mobile or not.

Header.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();  

  if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) 
    $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
  else
    $_SESSION['count']++;
?>
```

Footer.php:

```
<?php
  $count = $_SESSION['count'];

  if ($count == 1) {   
    //
  }
  elseif ($count >= 1 && $count <= 100) {
    if (wonderplugin_is_device('iPhone,iPod,Android'))
      echo get_function_mobile();
    else
      echo get_function();
  }
?>
```

Comment: This is a good PHP solution for the job, thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript and `localStorage` to remember the user's action :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  var previousAction = localStorage.getItem('user-action');
  if(previousAction)
  {
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
      jQuery('.slide-div').slideToggle();
    }, 2000);
  }
  else
  {
    localStorage.setItem('user-action', 'new-action-spotted');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this is not something I'm looking for. I want to trigger something **after** a visitor navigated to the next page. So, something like... `afterunload`, ;)

Comment: If I understand correctly and as @Sara Chipps said, you have to store the user's actions in order to do know/remember what he saw. To do this, you have several choices : cookie, localstorage, session...

Comment: Yes, this is indeed what I need. I would need to use PHP for this, right?

Comment: Yes, you can use PHP but I've updated my answer with a Javascript solution

Comment: Even though I ended up solving it with a PHP $_SESSION variable, this seems like the right solution for the job. I will add my used code below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a count of how many pages your users have been on you would need to hold onto a variable somewhere that is not on your page that you could increment with a page count. That may be in local storage, a cookie, or in your server side code.

Another thing you could do is add query strings to links on your pages if all you want to know is that someone has navigated from another page within your site. Then, check the query string on the page load and show your div if they are coming from an internal page.

Comment: This inspired me to come up with the solution mentioned below. thank you!